# Firestore: transaction and batch in one atomic operation

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, atomic

One atomic operation with a transaction and a batch together, is it possible in Firestore? or they are two different operations?

Answer (score 1):

A transaction is not the same as a batch.  And you can't perform a transaction inside a batch.  You have to choose.

You use a batch when you only have documents to create, or have known updates.  You use a transaction when you need to read documents first before modifying them.